# What are the main changes made to the game going from Civilization IV to V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What changes have been made from Civilization 4 to 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/what-changes-have-been-made-from-civilization-4-to-5)

What are the main differences between the two latest versions of the Sid's Meier Cilivization series?

Is this only an improvement of the graphical interface (more 3D and highly detailed views) or is this more than that?

Comment: There are quite a few differences between Civ 5 and Civ 4. A lot of long-time fans of the series prefer the previous installment. But... it's really a matter of personal taste and so subjective. I'm thinking this is too close to a game recomendation question.

Comment: According to you, the difference is more than a UI revamp : the game is diffrent too, isn't it?

Comment: There's quite a few changes in mechanics. For example, in Civ 5 you can only have one unit per tile. This restriction doesn't exist in Civ 4, so you can create massive forces and move them about as one.

Comment: Civ4 also uses squares, instead of hexagons; and many other changes. There are extensive lists on sites like civfanatics. But ultimately, whether you should buy Civ 4 is up to you. Personally, I haven't found much cause to go back to Civ 4 after Civ 5 came out, and I have around 150 hours on Civ 5 since launch, and probably double that amount on civ 4.

Comment: game recommendation questions are off-topic as per our [FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Wipqozn : Ok, sorry for that "buying-or-not" aspect. I totally re-pharse it to really keep the question clear. The background story wasn't really interesting and didn't add anything to my question.

Comment: Your question still runs into issues with the second portion of it. Asking users "Do you still play the fourth one" is a discussion question, and does not work for our site. I have edited those bits out of your question.

Comment: Ok, feel free to drop every "wrong" aspect of it. I don't want a debate of this, just to know if it's another game or not.

Comment: @Pierre I don't feel like writing up an answer right now, but there is a considerable difference between the two versions. The core game is still the same, but many of mechanics changed. Combat for example went over a major overhaul between IV and V.

Comment: For me, comment of TZHK and your last are totally the advices that I was looking for. Feel free to transmute them into anwsers :-P

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/what-changes-have-been-made-from-civilization-4-to-5

Comment: "Related" is quite weak ;-) I would tell "Duplicated" :-) Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many differences between Civilization 4 and 5. Besides the obvious graphic changes Some of the most significant game play changes are:

- 1 Military Unit per location, instead of infinite stacks
- Global happiness instead of local happiness
- Embarking troops instead of troop transport units.

An extensive list [can be found on the civfanatics forum.](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=436911)

Upcoming expansions might add or remove some of the differences. For example an announced expansion will add religion to Civilization 5, something which was already present in Civilization 4 but absent in the Civilization 5 base game.